# Run Dotfuscator as a post build event

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, post-build-event, dotfuscator

I'm using Dotfuscator in Visual Studio 2010.

I want to run Dotfuscator as a post build event so every time I build a project Dotfuscator will run on the output DLL using a configuration I've created and I'll get a new Dotfuscated DLL without having to manually open Dotfuscator.

After it will be obfuscated, I'll resign it (using sn.exe) and copy it to the directory where I use that DLL.

How can I run Dotfuscator as a post build event (or from command line)?

Answer (score 2):

The latest update to Dotfuscator CE (version 5.0.2600, released in August 2010) includes command line support for registered users.

Go here: http://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support for details.

Comment: Thanks mletterle. registered users = non free? As I said, I'm using the Dotfuscator available in VS2010. What does the upgrade requires? Thanks again.

Comment: registration is free, simply sign up for an account on the PreEmptive Solutions web site. See: http://www.preemptive.com/component/user/register

Comment: NOTE: as Lord of Scripts says in his later answer, community version does not include command line, at the time I write this.  Version comparison:  http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions

Comment: As of VS 2015 Update 3, Dotfuscator CE again includes command-line support for registered users. (Registration is free.) Visual Studio 2015 users not yet on Update 3 can download it (for free) from the website, if needed. See [this blog post](https://www.preemptive.com/blog/article/844-automate-your-builds-with-new-ce-command-line-support/91-dotfuscator-ce) for details. Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be lured into the PreEmptive stuff, after you register you get a right to download a 30 day trial/evaluation version and NOT a community version with command-line enabled. Their comparison page states clearly that the community version (free) does NOT have a command-line support.

Comment: As of VS 2015 Update 3, Dotfuscator CE does include command-line support for registered users. (Registration is free.) Visual Studio 2015 users not yet on Update 3 can download it (for free) from the website, if needed. See [this blog post](https://www.preemptive.com/blog/article/844-automate-your-builds-with-new-ce-command-line-support/91-dotfuscator-ce) for details. The [comparison page](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions) has been updated appropriately. Full disclosure: I work for PreEmptive Solutions.